# Picking the right Micro-Controller to interface with RFID and software developed in C#

Tags: c#, c, microcontroller, rfid, firmware

I am currenty leading a team in designing a new device which involves programming a microcontroller integrated with software.

My idea is fairly simple:

> - Use a Micro-controller to detect RFID(the kind in most hotel room cards, aka you hold it up to a scanner and it gets the RFID ID), then interface with a software application that will get written in C#.

Micro-controller requirements:

> - capability of reading RFID(should only need I/O pins for this I am assuming, so it can connect to a transceiver that broadcasts for ID).
> - capability of communicating with C# via usb.
> - should be programmable in C
> - should have pins on the board, proto-boards and circuits to run the micro-processor are trying to be avoided.

I have heard that a PIC32 would be a good option for this, not sure what board I would go after though.

A possible scanner i have found is the https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8628

What would be a good controller for this, I am not looking for super fast in terms of micro-controller, I just need it to do its job  and to reporte(the RFID ID) to the software?

I think C# would be the easiest lang to develop a software application in to do this project, does anyone else have any other suggestions?

I have a year to do this project.

Comment: This isn't really a code question. You might to take a look at: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ for language questions and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions for microcontroller questions

Comment: That being said, C# and Java are both easy to interface with serial ports/usb. There are tons of examples out there.

Comment: I've interfaced with RFID before, but it was a phidget kit - and it came with demo C# code. One of the easiest projects I've done, but phidget's not recommended for commercial distribution - is it a paid piece of work?

Comment: DeeMac, Its a school funded project. we get about 500-800$ for parts and have to to this project. Thanks for the reccomendation Nick.

Comment: http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Atmel/ATA2270-EK1/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtnum7fIZk9Pplg4zFf7%2fdgAtj70S%2fZITs%3d                                  AWSOME !

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable in C# you could use a .netmf board.  I have the [FEZ Panda II](http://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/256/) board which allows you to do write all your embedded code in .net + visual studio.  It utilizes an ARM processor.  Additionally this company offers a lot of different add-on modules that may be useful to you. The only caveat here is running a managed environment like this on a microprocessor doesn't give you a high degree of control over timing, from the sound of your project, this shouldn't be a big issue.  It's also a highly inexpensive solution and runs around the same pricing as something like an arduino.

Arduino are really easy to use as well and are more 'low-level' with less abstraction layers.  There is also a whole ton of add-ons for these as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your budget is max 800$ and if that includes the eval board, the RFID eval board, the programming tools, the compiler, the electronics, the PCB and the components, this restricts a lot you choice.

The works performed by the MCU doesn't look too complex: just passing packets between the UART (or SPI) connected to the RFID chip and the USB.
A simple, cheap MCU should be ok. No needs here for a powerful ARM.
I would suggest something such as a MSP430 from TI.
The c compiler is free for binaries smaller than 16k. Which seems the case here.
The debugger is affordable : 100$.
An eval board of MSP430 exists at ~30$.

But here it's not just a software problem. You have some electronics design to perform.
But it's the price to pay if you want a "product" at the end and not some eval board connected together which is more a kind proof of concept.